# python - entry.focus_set() not working in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, focus

I have an entry, a listbox(dropdown) and another listbox. Whenever more than 3 characters are typed inside the entry. A completion list is looked up and inserted to the dropdown and the dropdown is shown. If an item is selected from the dropdown. It's value should be inserted to the listbox and removed from the dropdown and the entry should get the focus again. But it doesn't.

**Here is my code:**

```
from tkinter import *


class Autocomplete(Frame, object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Autocomplete, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.text = StringVar()
        self.entry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.text)
        self.frame = Frame(self)
        self.listbox = Listbox(self.frame)
        self.dropdown = Listbox(self.frame)

    def build(self):
        self.text.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode: self._update_dropdown())
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.pack()
        self.frame.pack()
        self.listbox.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N)
        self.dropdown.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", lambda event: self._select_entry())
        self.dropdown.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N)
        self.dropdown.grid_forget()
        return self

    def _shorten_dropdown(self, index):
        self.dropdown.grid_forget()
        self.dropdown.delete(index)
        self.dropdown["height"] -= 1
        self.dropdown.selection_clear(0, END)
        self.dropdown.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N)

    def _select_entry(self):
        index = int(self.dropdown.curselection()[0])
        value = self.dropdown.get(index)
        self._shorten_dropdown(index)
        self.entry.focus_set()
```

This was the minimal code. [Here](http://codepad.org/8Z58dORk) is the testable version. And Here is the code to build an instance of autocompelete:

```
from tkinter import *
from autocomplete import Autocomplete

listt = ["a","aa","aaa","ab","bba","aba","abbnb","cd","c","abc","abcd"]
root = Tk()

autocomplete_frame = Autocomplete(
    60,
    10,
    listt
).build()
autocomplete_frame.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code is not testable. We need to be able to copy paste your code and see what your problem is. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can test your code.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I added a link to the complete code.

Comment: The link to your " testable version" is still not testable. How are you creating the object instance of `Autocomplete()`. there is no code that is calling that class. You do not need to provide all your code. Just a MCVE. This only needs to include the method in question and how you are creating your tkinter instance. You do not have `Tk()` or `mainloop()` in your code and it is required for tkinter to run. We need to be able to copy paste your example without having to guess as to how your are implementing your class.

Comment: The 2nd link you have should be a part of your original questions code.

Comment: @Mike-SMT fixed. Thanks:)

Comment: Is the typo `abc""` in `listt` apart of your original code? It could cause problems.

Comment: @Mike-SMT No. But sorry about the typo. in my original code the value of lisst is loaded from a file but I didn't put that here to summarize. but I guarantee nth is wrong with list. It just consists of alphanumeric strings.

Comment: Thats fine. I just noticed the type in your question so I thought I should point it out just in case. As for the rest of your code I am getting trackback errors when trying to implement your class. this line `super(Autocomplete, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` is causing problems. `TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`

Comment: Also `from settings import Settings` does not appear to be used in your example. You should not include imports unless they are relevant to the question. When we ask for the MCVE version of your code it is to make it easier to pinpoint your problem.

Comment: Working with your linked code and your question I am getting a index error on your `_select_entry(self)` method. Its not something I have worked with so I may not be able to answer it right away but that is where you should focus your research and figure out what it is you are trying to do here and why the index is out of range. `index = int(self.dropdown.curselection()[0])` is giving `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: Oh! I really wonder now! because I'm using the linked code exactly with the second code in the question and I don't get any error at all under any condition!@Mike-SMT

Comment: I corrected the problem by changing `index = int(self.dropdown.curselection()[0])` to `index = self.dropdown.curselection()[0]` as the value being returned is already and integer and cannot be converted to one. I am now trying to figure out what `if "results found for" in value:` is doing.

Comment: This code doesn't run.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have pointed that out as well. The code in the link combined with the 2nd portion of the code he provided with some cleaning up works and does reproduce the problem he is describing. I have asked for a MVCE but I am still trying despite the messy question.

Comment: Ok so I have your code working correctly now but only for 1 word. Are you needing to be able to continue typing and use the drop down to insert more words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a few things I had to change to get this to work for at least one word. Currently it will not work if you wish to continue typing out more words in a continuous string.

I am sure I can eventually get that to work as well but I am trying to answer the problem of updating a word from the list box and getting focus back to the entry field.

I had to change a couple things.

First I had to change:

```
index = int(self.dropdown.curselection()[0])
```

To:

```
index = self.dropdown.curselection()[0]
```

as the returned value of `self.dropdown.curselection()[0]` is already an int. It not needed to make the integer an integer again.

Second I had to change:

```
def _add_course(self, value):
    self.listbox.insert(END, value)
    self.my_list.append(value)
```

To:

```
def _add_course(self, value):
    self.entry.delete(0,END)
    self.entry.insert(END, value)
    self.my_list.append(value)
```

As you were trying to insert a the `value` into a listbox not the entry field. Also note I changed `self.list` to self.my_list`. You should avoid naming things that might overwrite built in functions.

The last thing I needed to change was how we were setting the focus back to the entry field. I believe the problem with the focus is the fact that you are setting a focus on mouse click however you are still clicking on the list box and that is taking focus. We need to add a delay to the focus set so that we have time to finish out mouse click before the focus is set to the entry field.

Change:

```
self.entry.focus_set()
```

to:

```
self.master.after(200, lambda: self.entry.focus())
```

An alternative to setting the focus back to the entry field would be to `bind()` the button release event to the focus command instead.

You can force focus like this as well:

```
self.dropdown.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda x: self.entry.focus())
```

The below code should work for your main problem:

```
from tkinter import *

class Autocomplete(Frame, object):
    def __init__(self, width, height, entries, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Autocomplete, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.my_list = []
        self._entries = entries
        self.listbox_height = height
        self.entry_width = width
        self.text = StringVar()
        self.entry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.text, width=self.entry_width)
        self.frame = Frame(self)
        self.listbox = Listbox(self.frame, height=self.listbox_height, width=self.entry_width)
        self.dropdown = Listbox(self.frame, height=self.listbox_height, width=self.entry_width, background="#cfeff9")

    def build(self):
        self.text.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode: self._update_dropdown())
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.pack()
        self.frame.pack()
        self.listbox.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N)
        self.dropdown.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", lambda event: self._select_entry())
        self.dropdown.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N)
        self.dropdown.grid_forget()
        return self

    def _update_dropdown(self):
        self.dropdown["height"] = self.listbox_height
        self.dropdown.delete(0, END)
        text = self.text.get()
        print("update: " + text)
        if len(text) < 3:
            self.dropdown.grid_forget()
            return
        else:
            for entry in self._entries:
                if entry not in self.my_list and text.lower() in entry.lower():
                    self.dropdown.insert(END, entry)
        listbox_size = self.dropdown.size()
        if not listbox_size:
            self.dropdown.insert(END, "No results found for '{}'".format(text))
            self.dropdown["height"] = 1
        else:
            if listbox_size <= self.dropdown["height"]:
                self.dropdown["height"] = listbox_size
        self.dropdown.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N)

    def _shorten_dropdown(self, index):
        print("shorten: {}".format(str(index)))
        self.dropdown.grid_forget()
        self.dropdown.delete(index)
        if self.dropdown["height"] == 1:
            self.dropdown.insert(END, "No more results found for '{}'".format(self.text.get()))
        else:
            self.dropdown["height"] -= 1
        self.dropdown.selection_clear(0, END)
        self.dropdown.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N)

    def _select_entry(self):
        index = self.dropdown.curselection()[0]
        value = self.dropdown.get(index)
        print(value)
        if "results found for" in value:
            print("return")
            return
        print("select: {}".format(value))
        self._shorten_dropdown(index)
        self._add_course(value)
        self.master.after(200, lambda: self.entry.focus())

    def _add_course(self, value):
        self.entry.delete(0,END)
        self.entry.insert(END, value)
        self.my_list.append(value)



listt = ["a","aa","aaa","ab","bba","aba","abbnb","cd","c","abc","abcd"]
root = Tk()

autocomplete_frame = Autocomplete(60, 10, listt).build()
autocomplete_frame.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: wow mike! You really tried so much to help. Tho, you did much more than what I needed, which is probably I failed to explain my goals and problems correctly. For the first edit I understand it's better to remove the int() but I don't get any error anyway. It mustn't be an error to cast an int to int again. For the second edit I think You got my goal wrong. the value shouldn't be inserted to the entry it should be inserted to a second listbox. But it doesn't matter. Thanks for the tip about naming. I will keep that in mind. And thing about the delay was my problem. And you fixed it for me!>:D<

Comment: @aran: Your question was a bit messy so I worked with what I thought your goal was. Sorry for the confusion. Take a look at my update for the focus portion. I have added a 2nd option for the focus part you may prefer to use.

Comment: yeah. that's actually even better. Thank you:)

Comment: @aran: About the listbox things. I only see one list box in your code. If you can maybe be more specific I might be able to answer that issue as well.

Comment: I have two listboxes. one is named listbox and the other is named dropdown. And there is no issue about that. Now Everything is working perfectly fine:)

Comment: @aran: Ok cool. I am glad my answer was able to solve your primary issue then.